How to calculate the product of 2 matrices that do not have commonality of interior dimensions?
I am trying to solve this seemingly simple matrix product problem:
Matrix A
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 1 & 0 \\ \hline 2 & 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}
Matrix B
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 3 & 0 & -1 \\ \hline 0 & 2 & -1 \\ \hline  \end{array}
Matrix A is a 2x2 matrix (2 rows, 2 columns)
Matrix B is a 2x3 matrix (2 rows, 3 columns)
As you can see, the number of rows in Matrix A isn't equal to the number of columns in Matrix B. For this reason, I am stuck and do not know how to proceed.
My understanding is that IF 2 matrices do not have commonality of interior dimensions (i.e., n≠p), then matrix multiplication is NOT possible. But this is a question I got during a test at uni. Was it a trick question then?

This is like asking how to compute 1/0. The matrix product $A B$ just isn't defined (and doesn't have any reasonable definition) if $A$ doesn't have as many columns as $B$ has rows.

Ok. So, basically, you are saying that if n≠p (i.e., number of columns in A isn't equal to number of rows in B), then matrix product is impossible, correct? I got this question during a test at uni, so I guess it was a well-intentioned trick question.

Yes, such “matrix products” don't make sense.

Thanks a lot! That is also what I thought. But I am still junior in maths, and the professor put this question in the test.

For matrix multiplication to be possible, the number of columns of the first matrix must equal the number of rows of the second matrix. In this case, we have Matrix A of 2 rows and 2 columns and Matrix B of 2 rows and 3 columns. Since Matrix A has 2 columns and Matrix B 2 rows, their product is possible:
Matrix A
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 1 & 0 \\ \hline 2 & 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}
Matrix B
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 3 & 0 & -1 \\ \hline 0 & 2 & -1 \\ \hline  \end{array}
To find the answer of A*B, we multiply each first and second column entries of B by the first and second row entries of A, respectively, and we sum the scores:
A times B
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 1 \cdot 3 + 0 \cdot 0 & 1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot 2 & 1 \cdot (-1) + 0 \cdot (-1) \\ \hline 2 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 0 & 2 \cdot 0 + 1 \cdot 2 & 2 \cdot (-1) + 1 \cdot (-1) \\ \hline  \end{array}
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 3 & 0 & -1 \\ \hline 6 & 2 & -3 \\ \hline  \end{array}
For those who are beginners in matrix multiplication, you can check this website that calculates matrix product for you AND shows you the detailed calculation: https://matrix.reshish.com/multiplication.php
Another useful textbook is "Mathematical Tools for Applied Multivariate Analysis" by J. Douglas Carroll and Paul E. Green.

I can't follow this. As far as I can see  $A$ is $2\times 2$ and $B$ is $2\times 3$ so there is no problem. [As you've not set your question using Mathjax it doesn't seem to display properly.]

I formatted the matrices and they showed normally in the pre-publishing preview but matrix A ended up not being properly displayed. I updated the post and appended an external image of the matrices instead. The number of rows in matrix A do not equal the number of cols in Matrix B. What is your take?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Dan_San to form matrix product $AB$, you need number of columns (the horizontal span) of $A$ equal to number of rows (the vertical span) of $B$.

I edited my answer. Thank you guys for your help. I think that the problem is now properly solved.
